# Javascript - Links in collapsing unordered list do not work

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I followed a tutorial to create a collapsing unordered list using Javascript and made some of the list items links. The problem is none of the links work on click. I have to right click and open in new tab to make it work.

The page in question is at: http://tinyurl.com/nc62ht3 
The link in the collapsing list is under: Firearms> Accessories> Buttstocks

Comment: Hi - welcome to Stackoverflow - links unfortunately go out of date, can you include a minimum example of your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `return false;` from that piece of code as it prevents links to redirect. As long as other clickable expandable navigation items are not anchors you can remove it.

```
function prepareList() {
    $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
     .click( function(event) {
    if (this == event.target) {
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
    }

    return false; // remove this
    })
    .addClass('collapsed')
    .children('ul').hide();
};

$(document).ready( function() {
     prepareList()
});
```